# Generate numbers orderly

Tags: php

I want generate a range of numbers orderly.  I mean opposite of **rand** function in **php**. I test with **range** but it generate only **array** of numbers 
For example 
 min 1 and max 3

```
rand(1,3);// 2,1,3
```

but i want 1,2,3

Any in built in functions in php like **rand** for getting this features without using any loops?

Comment: Do you want the result as an array or a string?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to generate numbers

```
// array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `for` loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        echo $i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`// array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {

    echo $number;

}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php then take a look at [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your slightly missleading question.. this might do it:

```
$string = implode(', ', range(1,3));
echo $string;
```

And not a loop in sight :)

Or as a one liner:

```
echo implode(', ', range(1,3));
```